# Android custom ViewPager is not allowing me to click on the View components

Tags: android, android-viewpager, click, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter with a custom ViewPager. Previously I was using a standard ViewPager and I was able to swipe to all my fragments correctly and interact with the EditTexts/Buttons and other components on the different Views, however I had to create a custom ViewPager when restricting the swipe direction.
Once I used the custom ViewPager, everything displays correctly etc however I am unable to click any of the EditTexts/Buttons etc.

Can anyone see the problem with this? I am assuming the SignUpPager is not overriding a certain method or incorrectly handling the MotionEvent.... but none of my attempts have worked.

SignUpPager.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;


public class SignUpPager extends ViewPager{
    public SignUpPager(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public SignUpPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    private float initialXValue;
    public SwipeDirection direction = SwipeDirection.all;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean IsSwipeAllowed(MotionEvent event) {
        if(this.direction == SwipeDirection.all) return true;

        if(direction == SwipeDirection.none )//disable any swipe
            return false;

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            initialXValue = event.getX();
            return true;
        }

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            try {
                float diffX = event.getX() - initialXValue;
                if (diffX > 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.right ) {
                    // swipe from left to right detected
                    return false;
                } else if (diffX < 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.left ) {
                // swipe from right to left detected
                return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public enum SwipeDirection {
        all, left, right, none ;
    }
}
```

In MainActivity.java I connect the SignUpPager to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter (note I have just copied the critical lines of code for this part):

```
public SignUpAdapter signUpAdapter;
public static SignUpPager pager;

signUpAdapter = new SignUpAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager = (SignUpPager) findViewById(R.id.signUpViewPager);
pager.setAdapter(signUpAdapter)

public static class SignUpAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
 ..........
}
```

sign_up.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <signUp.SignUpPager
        android:id="@+id/signUpViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_view.xml (this is the XML for the view of which I am unable to click the components) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/signUpLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
tools:context="com.example.tabbyreyez.helloworld.SignUpSecondaryController">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/signUpDataTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/signUpData"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:textSize="35dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstNameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First Name:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signUpDataTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="e.g. Tabraiz"
        android:layout_below="@+id/signUpDataTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:ems="9"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastNameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last Name:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstNameLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="e.g. Malik"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:ems="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwd"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you include the xml of your EditTexts/Buttons, the problem might lie there.

Comment: @REG1 I have updated with the xml file

Comment: Are you able to click on the views of the other fragment layouts?

Comment: @REG1 I have 3 fragments and I am able to swipe through all three without a problem. Im unable to click on any of the components inside any  of these 3 views when using my custom ViewPager (when I use the standard ViewPager it works though)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your MainActivity which should extend FragmentActivity.

```
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    //Initialize the pager
    this.initialisePaging();
}

/**
 * Initialize the fragments to be paged
 */
private void initialisePaging() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MyFragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MyFragment2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MyFragment3.class.getName()));
    this.myPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.signUpViewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
}
```

I see no reason why you should create your custom SignUpAdapter that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Instead, simply try using a PagerAdapter.

Comment: I the SignUpPager extends a ViewPager  not a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. And I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter since I require the user to actually swipe between fragments on a horizontal plane. Will a PagerAdapter achieve the same result? (p,s. I will conduct my own test asap)

Comment: @reyyez Sorry I meant SignUpAdapter. Yes, use my code that uses a PagerAdapter instead of your SignUpAdapter that extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter, it should work.

Comment: If it worked for you, please accept it as the answer :)

Comment: unfortunately using a PagerAdapter did not work either, the exact same problem persists (not being able to click the components on the views in the ViewPager)